# set docker container ip to global ip

Tags: docker, networking

I am currently trying to set a ip to container which can accessed by any other machine within the network. The network in which my docker-host machine is 9.158.143.0/24 with a gateway 9.158.143.254. 
Tried setting the ip(any free) within the subnet 9.158.143.0/24 with network type as bridge.It did not work(not even able to ping the container within docker host machine).
Then created a user defined network with subnet 9.10.10.0/24 and network driver as bridge. the container created is pingable but only within docker host machine.
Is there any way that this container be accessible from all the machine within the network(not just docker host machine).
PS: i do not want to expose the port.(Is changing routes helpful ..i know very little networking)

I aso tried userdefined network with macvlan driver. in this case i am able to ping container from other machines but not from docker host machine where container is present

Comment: Exposing the port is the docker way.    Or use host networking.

Comment: i cant add ip to container in host networking.

Comment: You can add the ip to the host in host networking (and then bind services in your container to that ip).

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to:

1- dedicate a new address for this container, on your local network;

2- configure this address as a secondary address on your docker engine host;

3- enable routing between local interfaces on your docker engine host;

4- use iptables to redirect the connections to this new address to your container.

Here is an example:

We suppose:

- your container instance is named `myinstance`
- your LAN network interface is named `eth0`
- you have chosen the available network address `192.168.1.178` on your LAN

So, you need to do the following:

- start your container (in this example, we start a web server):

  `docker run --rm -t -i --name=mycontainer httpd:2.2-alpine`
- enable local IP routing:

  `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`
- add a secondary address for your container:

  `ip addr add 192.168.1.178/24 dev eth0`
- redirect connections for this address to your container:

  First, find your container local address:

  % docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' mycontainer

  172.17.0.2

  Now, use this local address with `iptables`:

  iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 192.168.1.178/32 -j DNAT --to 172.17.0.2

Finally, you can check it works by accessing http://192.168.1.178/ from any other host on your LAN.

Comment: hi the iptables command seems to be not working..I tried these steps but cannot connect via 192.168.1.178. is the routing command used(internally) when we use port exposing in docker.

Comment: What is the ip address of the host from which you try to connect to 192.168.1.178?

Comment: 9.158.143.52(same subnet as that of docker host(mine docker host-9.158.143.51))..any way to check that iptables rule is added??

Comment: As said in my answer, you need to choose an available Ip on your lan. Your lan seems to be 9.158.143.0/24. So, replace the value in my example, 192.168.1.178, by an availlable Ip on your lan and try again, please.

Comment: yeah actually did that already i chose 9.158.143.61..which was free..added it to the primary interface and then used in routing command..

Comment: Ok, can you ping 9.158.143.61 from your host 9.158.143.52? Do you get a reply from it?

Comment: Ca you check that your container is still running?

Comment: Do you have a linux firewall activated on this node?

Comment: Can you write the output of "sysctl -A | grep ip_forward | grep v4" please?

Comment: output:root@nc143052-kraklab:~# sysctl -A | grep ip_forward | grep v4
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.all.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.br-62c0f795c03d.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.default.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.docker0.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.docker_gwbridge.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.ens160.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.lo.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.veth06ffa4e.stable_secret"

Comment: sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.vethfadc07e.stable_secret"
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward_use_pmtu = 0

Comment: hi Alexandro thanks for the help command working              
root@nc143052-kraklab:~# iptables -t nat -A DOCKER -d 9.158.143.61/24 ! -i docker0 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2